# Scheduling Requirements instead of Tasks or Features?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am trying to understand why DevOps does not allow start/finish dates for Requirements (CMMI process) as opposed to seemingly just Features and Tasks? In addition, it's odd that if I add a Requirement to an Iteration (which has dates), I see it on a Delivery plan:
[image]

I can move it out of the sprint by dragging the start date and end date out in the Delivery Plan, [image]

But don't see any date information on the ticket itself?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that since Epics and Features are likely to span sprints, you'd use these dates to build a plan. But Requirements should be small enough in a sprint and would take their dates from there.

The start date and end date of the Requirement (comparable to a User Story or Product Backlog Item) are automatically filled when a Requirement is put to In Progress and Done. The Delivery Plan has no direct relation to these fields, hence why the fields are read-only.

Remember that Delivery Plans works the same across the Agile and Scrum and CMMI templates, as such a number of assumptions are made about your delivery process: you work in sprints and work performed in a sprint is generally finished within the sprint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, that does make sense. I am not seeing (Start Date or End Date) get updated however for the Requirement when changing State to Active when it is assigned to a sprint though. Oddly enough though, if I drag the start date on the Delivery Plan for the Requirement after adding it to the Sprint, it *does* set the Start Date?? Is there anything I might be missing here?

Comment: Arg.its a nightmare lately with what works and doesn't and where it works when it does.

Comment: appreciate your feedback, thanks. Is there a way you know of for me to log a bug or get some clarity from the Azure team?

Comment: I logged this feedback here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Start-Date-and-End-Date-of-CMMI-Requirem/1639401?space=21